# Why my media query not working after following all rules of media queries also?

Tags: html, css

[image: I have followed all the rules of media queries, like using the viewport, using the correct syntax, the correct place from where I have to call the media query, targeting the element to use the media query, and covering all elements from the top to bottom of the targeting element and match them also from style.css and media.css, but my media queries are still not working, and I don't know what I am doing wrong.]

I have followed all the rules of media queries, like using the viewport, using the correct syntax, the correct place from where I have to call the media query, targeting the element to use the media query, and covering all elements from the top to bottom of the targeting element and match them also from style.css and media.css, but my media queries are still not working, and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please create SO Snippet that shows your issue. Right now we can't inspect your code to know what's actually wrong

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

You need to familiarise yourself with [the cascade](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade#cascading_order). It is such an important feature of CSS that it forms part of the name.

Rules are applied in a particular order. If you have conflicting rules (such as two attempts to set the `max-width`) then it is the cascade which determines which one applies.

The final rule for the cascade (once everything else that influences it is equal) is that the rule later in the source code will overwrite the rule earlier in the source code.

Your rules on line 1112 (outside of any media query) overwrite all the rules inside media queries (such as those on line 679).

Comment: At the moment what can I do because as you said for max-width so I removed it and tried again but still it is not working?

Comment: You completely missed the point. Reread the penultimate paragraph again. *the rule later in the source code will overwrite the rule earlier in the source code*. You need to **change the order** in  your source code.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I do this?

Comment: Select the block of code you want to move. Then select cut. Then click where you want to move it to. Then click paste.

Comment: But buddy "1112" line of code is in style.css and the "679" line of code is in media.css. So you want to say that I have to move the block of the styling of codes from the "1112" line and move it to the upper side that is from the upper side of the "679" line?

Comment: Move the HTML that lots the media styles after the HTML that loads the styles styles.

Comment: No man this is not working. I think the problem is different which you also do not catching. This is the first time when I was trapped in this type of situation.

Comment: They have equal specificity. They have the same property names. They aren't `!important`.  Earlier ones are crossed out. Everything says that the order is the issue.